# How can I find the number of keys in a hash in Perl?

Tags: perl, hash

How do I find the number of keys in a hash, like using `$#` for arrays?

Answer (score 89, accepted):

```
scalar keys %hash
```

or just

```
keys %hash
```

if you're already in a scalar context, e.g. `my $hash_count = keys %hash`  or  `print 'bighash' if keys %hash > 1000`.

Incidentally, `$#array` doesn't find the number of elements, it finds the last index.  `scalar @array` finds the number of elements.

Comment: $#+1 - we will get no of elements . i am meaning that for $#

Comment: Ah, I see.  Well, I would still recommend `scalar @array` over `$#array + 1`. :)

Comment: is there any particular reason for that

Comment: It's a single operation instead of two, and I try to write code that "asks for what it means" instead of arriving at what it means by some slightly-too-clever alternate route.

Comment: Of course, if you use `keys` in scalar context, e.g. in an assignment to a scalar or in a conditional, you do not even need the `scalar` making this even simpler.

Comment: @Krish: `$#arr + 1` will give you the number of elements in the array iff `$[ == 0` (see `perldoc perlvar`)

Answer (score 3):

we can use like this too

```
my $keys = keys(%r) ;
print "keys = $keys" ;

 0+(keys %r)
```

Comment: i found this after posted in so

Answer (score 0):

But not after Perl 5.10:

```
use feature ":5.10";
my %p = ();
say $#%p;

# $# is no longer supported
```

and worse:

```
use feature ":5.10";
my %p = (a=>1, b=>2, c=>3);
say $#{%p};

# -1
```

Answer (score -1):

```
print scalar keys %hash;
```

or

```
$X = keys %hash;
print $X;
```

`keys %hash` returns the value of keys in the list context that further changes into the scalar context (when assigning to scalar variable).

Comment: How does this answer differ than the accepted answer?

Answer (score -4):

This will work in easy way and for any size of a hash.

print scalar keys %hash;

Comment: Sorry but... how does this differ from the heavily-upvoted, accepted answer, posted 7 years ago, other than using `print`?